# Finding the Integral´s interval for a Probability Function

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]

The probability density function of a given random variable is given by the graph below. How can I set up the integral in order to find P(X>0, P(X>3/4).

I tried to set up the integral and this is my attempt.

For the P(X>0, P(X>3/4), I have set the integral as [image: From zero until 1/2]. The first picture is from 0 until 0.5(1/2) and the second is from 0.5 until 3/4.
[image: From 1/2 until 1]

Comment: Where is your attempt ?

Comment: What is your probability density function (densidade de probabilidade) ?

Comment: So, sometimes we just need a confirmation of our work. It´s a pitty that someone may vote down for a question. Nobody knows everything in the Universe.

Comment: Don´t care about the (down)votes. They are often not comprehensible.

Comment: It looks to me as if $\Pr(X\gt 0,X\gt 3/4)$ is just $\Pr(X\gt 3/4)$. This is $\int_{3/4}^1 1\,dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The pdf is

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}  0.5, \ \ -0.5 < x \leq 0.5 \\ 1 , \ \ 0.5 < x \leq 1 \\ 0 \ \ \ \ \text{elsewhere}  \end{cases}$$

Thus $P(X>0,X>3/4)=P(X>3/4)=\int_{3/4}^1 1 \, dx$

It is comprehensible ? Can you go on, without using wolfram alpha ?

Comment: What does the comma mean in this case?

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra $P(X>0,X>3/4)$ has the same meaning as $P(X>0 \cap X>3)$ It is the intersection. Thus $X$ is greater $0$ and greater $3$ It is obvious that the condition $X>0$ is redundant. If it is not obvious then have a look on a number line.